# Обработчик ошибок в контроллере Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, api, rest

У меня есть сайт, написаный на Yii2. Сейчас пишу для него api. И мне надо изменить формат отдачи ошибок. Как тут - [ссылка](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-error-handling), только сделать это не для всего сайта, а для 1-го контроллера. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, когда наследуешь класс контроллера от yii\rest\Controller, то все преобразовывается автоматически

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо создать свой класс ResponseCustom и унаследовать его от yii\web\Response. В конфигурации приложения указать ResponseCustom вместо yii\web\Response и передать список контроллеров, для которых необходимо изменить формат ответа.